# How to replace every x-th occurence of a string in a text with RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

A sample text is
`"abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "`
where `abc` could be every string of any length  (`.*`) except the 4-char-string `", "`.

For my test case where 
the search needle is the four chars `", "` 
and every 4th occurence should be replaced

I came up with
`(([^(", ")]*", "[^(", ")]*){3})", "`
and 
`((.*", ".*){3})", "`

Those both do not work in notepad++ when using it's regex search. (I just see I didn't try them in the browser scratchpad. But I suspect the error anyway in my regex-term.)

For replacement I tried `$1", \n"`.

What's the right regex and the right replacement?

Bonus question :) 
How to achieve, that the `"` of the search needle will be used for the count of the next 4 occurences of the needle?

Maybe another description:

```
addLineBreaksToLongString(a="text",b="-, -",k=3,d=3) {
// a the String, b signal string to break at, k number of letters of b to keep on old line, d only break at every d-th occurence of b
```

(I have written a javascript function to achieve this. So no need to put time in posting one. I want to improve my regex writing, because it's much faster to use in single cases.)

Comment: What exactly is wrong in notepad++? The only thing I can think of atm is that notepad++ might not like escaped characters in replacement.

Comment: Why don't you try it in here for example:
https://regex101.com/r/cU5lC2/1#javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally this works:

```
((.*?", "){3}.*?)", "
```

and as replacement

```
$1", \n"
```

This works in notepad++, too.

To match new-line characters, too, instead of `.*` use `[\S\s]*`:

`(([\S\s]*?", "){3}[\S\s]*?)", "`

as `.*` possibly doesn't match new-line characters, depending on the regex engine used.

Answer (score 1):

This regex captures every fourth `", "` in $1:

`".+?", ".+?", ".+?", ".+?(", ")`

It uses the lazy `.+?` to ensure it doesn't eat too much.

Answer (score 1):

With notepad++:

search:`(?:("[^\\"]*+(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*+"):(?1),\K ){4}`
replace:`\n`

The pattern supports escaped double quotes and trim the last space.

Comment: @John: strange, I have tested it with notepad++ (6.8.3) with the string you posted in comment and it works well.

Comment: @John, because a space is missing here `:"space-around","ruby-position":` (but you can easily make it optional in the pattern)